# Dashboard's Lifetime Sales And Total Order Revenue are displaying different values ? Any Solutions?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, reports, sales, totals

I have a problem with dashboard's Lifetime Sales and Revenue displays different figure.

i have tried displayed lifetime sales by following code:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')->calculateSales()->load()->getFirstItem()->getLifetime();
```

and it is displaying correct, same amount as Lifetime Sales on dashboard.

so i am getting confused whether lifetime sales is wrong or /revenue is wrong.

[image]

Another Snap :

[image]

Can any body help me???

Comment: One of the two sums only the completed orders, when I remember correctly

Comment: I believe @FabianBlechschmidt is correct. Only orders that are marked as 'completed' status contribute to dashboard totals.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing lifetime statistics under Reports > Refresh Statistics

Comment: you can see in the picture, it's refreshed just 2 days ago..
Any other solution ?

Comment: Lifetime statistics - are you sure? Not just 'last day'. Any output from the general PHP error log or the Magento Exception log?

Comment: @philwinkle **Yes** , I have just Refreshed the "Lifetime Statistics"
And also there are no Error or warning Logs in PHP and Magento Log Files.. Still Same Problem Stucked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the graph for the dashboard used the default timezone (not your store timezone), whereas the reports use your timezone. So the figures could be as much as 12 hours out either way. But its normally fairly insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime sales is based on completed orders I believe. Try running a report on the different order status instead of any. I did this and it showed the matching numbers, thought mine was not off by such a dramatic number.

So the Revenue that you see on the right is all orders, regardless of status (except canceled I think)